# i have 6 products and i want to show 3 products on per row using php foreach

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing an e-commerce website using php. There I want to display 3 products per row (I have 6 of them) using php `foreach`. Here is my code:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        $numOfCols = 4;
        $rowCount = 0;
        $bootstrapColWidth = 12 / $numOfCols;
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($results as $product) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-<?php echo $bootstrapColWidth;?>">
                <div class="well" style="width: 250px;height: auto;">
                    <div><?php echo'<img src="' . base_url().'uploads/' . $product- 
>product_image . '">'; ?></div>
                <?php echo $product->name;?> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $rowCount++;
        if($rowCount % $numOfCols == 0) {echo '</div><div 
        class="row">'.'<br>'.'<br>';
        }
        ?>
        <?php };?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code makes it show all products in a single column. I don't know how to make it show this in 2 columns instead.

Comment: The question is mostly about html/css/bootstrap, not php, so I've edited the question accordingly. I've also improved formatting so that the code is more readable, please do so in your next questions (I believe there's also 2 linebreaks that were not meant to be here).

Comment: ok l will try this

Comment: but issue remains the same

Comment: You should not need counters at all. A simple loop that drops each entry into a BS  column classed as `col-4` or `col-md-4` or whatever (4 being the key if you want three per "row"). The rest should take care of itself. The columns will stack 3 wide if they are all within one `div.row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//initialize a counter 
$count = 0;

//start the table 
echo("<table><tr>"); 
foreach ($products as $product) {

//if it's divisible by 5 then we echo a new row 
if(($count % 5) == 0){

echo("</tr><tr>\n"); 
$count++;

}//if 
else{ 
$count++; 
}
echo("<td>$product<td>");

}//foreach

//close the table 
echo("</tr></table>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`array_chunk()`** function over your products array which splits an array into chunks of new arrays. Loop over a new array and display products as you like.
For more information about **`array_chunk()`** visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php.

Hint:

```
$productsArray = array_chunk($results,3);//chunks 3 products on each sub array
foreach($productsArray as $products)
{
  //loop here your products with <div class="row"></div>..
}
```

Comment: now also it showing only 2 images in a single column

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is using a counter variable. Before loop set the value of the counter variable as 0 and increment it each time after printing the product.

Also, keep the body of the foreach loop in an if condition where it will check the value of the counter variable. If the value is equal to 3 reset it to 0 and then print the product after adding a new `</div><div class="row">` tags.

Code is as follows:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                $bootstrapColWidth = 12 / $numOfCols;
                //Setting the counter variable
                $counter = 0;
                foreach ($results as $product) { 
                    //Checking the value of counter variable and then implementing the corresponding code
                    if($counter == 3){
                        $counter=0;
            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
            <?php
                    }else{
                        $counter++;
                    }
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-<?php echo $bootstrapColWidth;?>">
                <div class="well" style="width: 250px;height: auto;">
                    <div><?php echo'<img src="' . base_url().'uploads/' . $product->product_image . '">'; ?></div>
                <?php echo $product->name;?> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php };?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this logic works for you.

Comment: //initialize a counter 
$count = 0;

//start the table 
echo("<table><tr>"); 
foreach ($products as $product) {

//if it's divisible by 5 then we echo a new row 
if(($count % 5) == 0){

echo("</tr><tr>\n"); 
$count++;

}//if 
else{ 
$count++; 
}

echo("<td>$product<td>");

}//foreach

//close the table 
echo("</tr></table>");

Comment: anyway thank you very much to all those who gave me support